# Rails: Custom behavior for specific HTTP error codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, error-handling, http-headers

I am working on a RoR website and would like to handle server errors (400, 404, 500, etc.) individually. Also, since the website is dynamic I would like to handle the errors within the rails environment rather than at the server level.
An example of what I would like to do could be to present the user with optional material or a search bar when she bumps into a page or template that will not load or simply does not exist.

So, I did a bit of reading and I think that using the rescue_from exception handler is the way to go in my case. (Would be more than happy to hear if any of you have a different opinion).

I have a simple working prototype (see code below) up and running, however, I get an error when I include the following exception handler to the code:

```
rescue_from ActionController::MissingTemplate,          :with => :not_found #404
```

Now, I can't see that I have a spelling error and I have seen this line in code posted on the web. However, when I include it I get the following routing error:

```
Routing Error No route matches "/errorhandle" with {:method=>:get}
```

I am working on rails 2.3.5, perhaps that has got something to do with it?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    helper :all # include all helpers, all the time

    protect_from_forgery #See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details

    #ActiveRecord exceptions
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :not_found #400   

    #ActiveResource exceptions  
    rescue_from ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound, :with => :not_found #404

    #ActionView exceptions
    rescue_from ActionView::TemplateError, :with => :not_found #500

    #ActionController exceptions
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :not_found #404   

    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, :with => :not_found #404 

    rescue_from ActionController::MethodNotAllowed, :with => :not_found #405   

    rescue_from ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken, :with => :not_found #405

    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, :with => :not_found #501

    # This particular exception causes all the rest to fail.... why?
    # rescue_from ActionController::MissingTemplate, :with => :not_found #404
    
    protected
    def not_found
        render :text => "Error", :status => 404
    end

    # Scrub sensitive parameters from your log
    # filter_parameter_logging :password 
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant routes from routes.rb, if any?

Comment: Sure Trevoke, thanks for the quick reply.
I haven't added anything to routes.rb so I guess this is pretty much the std. file:

ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :errorhandlers

# ...
# lots of lines commented out
# ...

 map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
 map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end

Comment: uh, not sure how to make the comment look nice and tidy *uark*.
Hope it's readable anyways...

Comment: Edit your question to make the routes look nice and tidy

Comment: Veger: Can't seem to edit it now but I will work out how to do it for the next post. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a quick look at these:
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/47898

http://henrik.nyh.se/2008/09/404-invalid-rails-format

In particular, a post in the first link:

> You can't use a regular 'rescue' keyword to rescue MissingTemplate 
>   exception.
>
> Use rescue_action instead, for example:

```
def rescue_action(exception)
  if ::ActionController::MissingTemplate === exception
     render :text => 'rescued'
  else
     super
  end
end
```

> Kent.

Comment: Thanks very much Kent for your reply and the links, they were all very helpful. I will read up on the :: and general exception handling in RoR to better understand your reply. ...and then I might throw a few more questions out there if you don't mind?

For now - thanks to all of you, it's great being part of such an active forum!

/Maja

Comment: I'm not Kent - Kent is the one who answered that question in the first link :-)
You're welcome. By all means, ask more questions, that's what this website is for! (just read the doc first, of course).